# python cx_Oracle to dump database objects another server

Tags: python, oracle, oracle10g, cx-oracle

I want to dump oracle objects like tables and stored procedures using cx_Oracle from python ,
is any tutorial how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the source code for tables you can use the following:

```
select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','<table_name>') from DUAL;
```

for stored procedures you can use

```
select text from all_source where name = '<procedure name>'
```

In general this is not a cx_Oracle specific problem, just call the oracle specific tables (like `all_source`) or functions (like `get_ddl`) and read it in like any other query.  There are more of these sorts of tables (like `user_source` for source that you the specific user own) in Oracle, but I'm doing this off the top of my head and don't have easy access to an Oracle db to remind myself.